# SQLite + Visual Studio 2015 Design-Time support Test application missing test database

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, ado.net, visual-studio-2015

On my `Windows 8.1` laptop, I installed `sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.99.0.exe` from [SQLite.org](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) website. The installer created a short cut in the Window's start menu that contains a Test application (shown below) installed by the installer. The connection string (in the figure below) shows a Data Source to be Test.db. But when I run the app I get the `database not found` error. I searched for the Test.db file in the installation directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\System.Data.SQLite\2015` but could not find this file.

[image]